# Can an Ember component listen for a route's didTransition action?

Tags: ember.js

I have a Ember.Component that wraps a js grid layout algorithm.  It works well on a reload, but doesn't respond to route transitions.  Say I transition from item\1 to item\2 I'd like the component to re-layout the grid.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  this._super();
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.afterRenderEvent);
},  
afterRenderEvent: function() { 
  //re-layout grid
}
```

How do I respond to the route's didTransition action?  How should I accomplish this?

Comment: What are you passing to the component? If you are passing the model you can observe `model.id` and do your thing accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No a component cannot listen for a route's `didTransition` event, as least not using Ember out of the box. You could set up some kind of pub-sub system, but I'd recommend against that.

To solve the problem you're facing, you need to find a way for the component to do what it needs using only data passed into it. The general flow is that, on transition a controller will receive a new model and update its state, then pass that state down into the component which then updates itself accordingly. Your component's visual display should only be based on the properties passed into it, and it should update accordingly when those properties change. If you find yourself having to update your component through other means, your code is likely too coupled.

Comment: Also, if you're having trouble designing your components in such a way, feel free to post a new question giving us a few more details. This definitely isn't an easy problem to solve.

Comment: I understand the issue with having tightly coupled components, and in general this isn't a problem.  However, in this specific case it would be nice to just know that the route has transitioned so that a css layout pass can occur.

Comment: Without using private API, there's simply no way to do it within Ember. If you absolutely must get that message to the component, I would recommend using a pub-sub system like I said in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could probably do something like this (tested and works with Ember 2.9.1):

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  router: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),

  didInsertElement() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
      this.get('router').on('didTransition', function() {
        // didTransition
      });
    });
  }
})
```

You also need to create an initializer, which injects the router into components:

```
export default {
  name: 'component-router-injector',
  initialize: function(application) {
    application.inject('component', 'router', 'router:main');
  }
}
```